# Comparing two data sets returning the biggest on both

Tags: r

I have a problem where I need to look at two sets of data. These are the same data values just sorted differently. From these sets I need to produce the value which is the highest on both. As I tend to over complicate things I am hoping the community can help.

The set being used is mtcars, I have created a sort of this call it byMPG and one call it byHP. Now I want to compare MPG and HP and produce which ever car is highest on MPG but also shows up highest on HP. So for example sorting by MPG the Toyota Corolla comes up in the first position. Yet on HP it is almost dead last and thus would not be the answer. I am assuming that I need to create a statement in which the value is returned if highest on byMPG and highest on byHP but I know that would produce a false or 0 as Maserati does not equal Toyota. Thank you in advance for your help on this issue.

```
myCars <- mtcars
byMPG <- myCars[order(-myCars$mpg),]
byHP <- myCars[order(-myCars$hp),]
byMPG
byHP
```

As I am not familiar with how to format this I am assuming I am over complicating this for this point in learning. Looking at the data it looks like the answer should be Lotus Europa as it is third on MPG and shows up first on the HP table.

Comment: You mention what would be a wrong answer. But, what would be a right answer?

Comment: @dylanjm thank you for your response, I mention what I believe would be the right answer at the last line of the question.

Comment: I think, I'm either missing details or you're thinking about your problem the wrong way. It seems to me you'd be better off just visually looking on the table. I'm not sure how you'd put this an algorithm. Do you value HP more than mpg? Why is 33/66 worse than 30/113? It just seems a little arbitrary.

Comment: If you want the car model as the result it's going to be difficult to get the max from both because like you said, Toyota is top mpg but last hp. So it's going to be hard to determine best of both without more details.

Comment: @dylanjm aye the question as written is "Which car has the 'best' combination of mpg and hp?" Well whats best ? which is weighted more? Can i do a simple multiplication of the data and that result is whats best? When i did that i came up with the car who won HP sort as the victor.

Comment: Well, in that case, there many different ways to splice it since you can multiply each value by a certain pct that add up to 1 or you can take the sum of both columns and determine that's completely up to you. So it's not really clear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: by rank, `mtcars[order(rank(mtcars$mpg) + rank(mtcars$hp)), ]` though it probably makes more sense to use quantiles: `mtcars[order(do.call(\`+\`, lapply(mtcars[c('mpg', 'hp')], function(x) (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))))), ]`

Comment: I think this may answer the question posed, the engine rating?
`efficency <- data.frame(myCars, (myCars$mpg/myCars$hp))
colnames(efficency)[colnames(efficency)=="X.myCars.mpg.myCars.hp."] <- "eff"
efficency <- efficency[order(-efficency$eff),]
index <-which.max(efficency$eff)
rownames(efficency)[index]`

Answer (score 0):

the provided solution to this problem was the following I will leave it here for future use:

```
myCars <- mtcars
myCars$efficiency <- scale(myCars$mpg) + scale(myCars$hp)
row.names(myCars)[which.max(myCars$efficiency)]
```